# Unable to create a Webhook for my Facebook Chatbot

Tags: facebook, messenger, dialogflow-es, pythonanywhere, facebook-chatbot

Dears,
I've been following this tutorial to create a chatbot,by using Facebook Messenger:
https://chatbotnewsdaily.com/build-a-facebook-messenger-chat-bot-in-10-minutes-5f28fe0312cd

I've completed all and I'm just about to deploy the webhook. The only problem is that on the step 4:**(create our WebHook), click “Setup Webhooks”**. I got 2 different messages on the Callback Url (red x), one was that the url returns “Hello World (from Flask!)”, instead of a numerical value that the system expects. 
The last message was now that the http Error 403. Any hints?

It seems like there is a problem with security - shall part of this code be changed to make it work/accepted by Facebook authentication?

The code is embedded in the page link.

Comment: Have you made sure that the verify token you specified in your FB app settings matches the one the code tests for?

Comment: Hi @CBroe, yes I did. I am still receiving this message: The URL couldn't be validated. Callback verification failed with the following errors: HTTP Status Code = 403; HTTP Message = FORBIDDEN

Comment: Well then you have to find out why your server/system felt inclined to answer with that status code ... https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ has instructions on how to start debugging in the environment they provide.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe :) It could be because I'm using a non-paid account for pythonanywhere, what do you think?